# Delete files with string found in file - Linux cli

Tags: linux, file, find, command-line-interface, rm

I am trying to delete erroneous emails based on finding the email address in the file via Linux CLI.

I can get the files with

`find . | xargs grep -l email@example.com`

But I cannot figure out how to delete them from there as the following code doesn't work.

`rm -f | xargs find . | xargs grep -l email@example.com`

Answer (score 80, accepted):

For safety I normally pipe the output from find to something like awk and create a batch file with each line being "rm filename"

That way you can check it before actually running it and manually fix any odd edge cases that are difficult to do with a regex

```
find . | xargs grep -l email@example.com | awk '{print "rm "$1}' > doit.sh
vi doit.sh // check for murphy and his law
source doit.sh
```

Comment: I liked your approach, but for me couldn't do it because I needed a cron job :P So I'm going with this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/4529188/656094

Comment: How can I count the number of deleted files? piping the command to ```wc -l``` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What about a `find . -type f` ?

Answer (score 86):

Solution for your command:

```
grep -l email@example.com * | xargs rm
```

Or

```
for file in $(grep -l email@example.com *); do
    rm -i $file;
    #  ^ prompt for delete
done
```

Comment: For several files, you can prevent the wildcard adding too many arguments by using `grep -l -R --include="*" email@domain.com ./` instead

Comment: `sudo grep -lr '/directory/youd/like/to/delete/from/' -e 'text you would like to search' | xargs rm`  This is what I used. I believe 2grit referenced the '-r' for recursive, which was helpful in my case.

Answer (score 21):

You can use `find`'s `-exec` and `-delete`, it will only delete the file if the `grep` command succeeds. Using `grep -q` so it wouldn't print anything, you can replace the `-q` with `-l` to see which files had the string in them.

```
find . -exec grep -q 'email@example.com' '{}' \; -delete
```

Comment: does `find . -exec grep -q 't-bone@spechal.com' '{}' \; -print` show anything?

Comment: yeah, but nothing as expected. `find . |grep 't-bone@spechal.com'` at other hand works just fine. I'm on a mac, btw. my answer there solved it for me anyway. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Despite Martin's safe answer, if you've got certainty of what you want to delete, such as in writing a script, I've used [this](http://munkymorgy.blogspot.com.br/2009/02/using-xargs-on-mac-terminal.html) with greater success than any other one-liner suggested before around here:

```
$ find . | grep -l email@example.com | xargs -I {} rm -rf {}
```

But I rather find by name:

```
$ find . -iname *something* | xargs -I {} echo {}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
rm -f `find . | xargs grep -li email@example.com`
```

does the job better. Use `...` to run the command to offer the file names containing `email.@example.com` (`grep -l` lists them, `-i` ignores case) to remove them with `rm` (`-f` forcibly / `-i` interactively).

Answer (score 3):

I liked Martin Beckett's solution but found that file names with spaces could trip it up (like who uses spaces in file names, pfft :D). Also I wanted to review what was matched so I move the matched files to a local folder instead of just deleting them with the 'rm' command:

```
# Make a folder in the current directory to put the matched files
$ mkdir -p './matched-files'

# Create a script to move files that match the grep
# NOTE: Remove "-name '*.txt'" to allow all file extensions to be searched.
# NOTE: Edit the grep argument 'something' to what you want to search for.

$ find . -name '*.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 grep -al 'something' | awk -F '\n' '{ print "mv \""$0"\" ./matched-files" }' > doit.sh

Or because its possible (in Linux, idk about other OS's) to have newlines in a file name you can use this longer, untested if works better (who puts newlines in filenames? pfft :D), version:

$ find . -name '*.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 grep -alZ 'something' | awk -F '\0' '{ for (x=1; x<NF; x++) print "mv \""$x"\" ./matched-files" }' > doit.sh

# Evaluate the file following the 'source' command as a list of commands executed in the current context:
$ source doit.sh
```

---

NOTE: I had issues where grep could not match inside files that had utf-16 encoding.
See [here](https://www.splitbits.com/2015/11/11/tip-grep-and-unicode/) for a workaround. In case that website disappears what you do is use grep's -a flag which makes grep treat files as text and use a regex pattern that matches any first-byte in each extended character. For example to match Entité do this:

```
grep -a 'Entit.e'
```

and if that doesn't work then try this:

```
grep -a 'E.n.t.i.t.e'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
find . | xargs grep -l email@example.com
```

how to remove:

```
rm -f 'find . | xargs grep -l email@example.com'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. - [From review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/11620068)

Comment: Find works, remove not (centos 6)

Answer (score 1):

Quick and efficent. Replace `find_files_having_this_text` with the text you want to search.

```
grep -Ril 'find_files_having_this_text'  . |  xargs rm
```